# Kafka message logs not purging

Tags: apache-kafka

We have retention policy of 7 days and message log files are rotated. But we have files as old as 30 days. It meets the criteria for getting deleted - log segments are rolled over and time period is greater than retention period. From following, all Dec logs should ideally be deleted. Does anyone know the reason why it may not get deleted. Current date is Jan 14.

```
-rw-r--r--    1  2.8M Dec  7 17:40 00000000000000946249.log
-rw-r--r--    1 5.6K Dec 11 17:45 00000000000000946249.index
-rw-r--r--    1  3.0M Dec 18 17:37 00000000000000968863.log
-rw-r--r--    1  5.9K Dec 18 17:49 00000000000000968863.index
-rw-r--r--    1  1.4M Dec 25 17:49 00000000000000992738.log
-rw-r--r--    1  2.7K Dec 25 17:50 00000000000000992738.index
-rw-r--r--    1  1.8M Jan  1 17:48 00000000000001003504.log
-rw-r--r--    1  3.5K Jan  1 18:00 00000000000001003504.index
-rw-r--r--    1  1.7M Jan  8 17:58 00000000000001017787.log
-rw-r--r--    1  3.3K Jan  8 18:00 00000000000001017787.index
drwxr-xr-x  2  4.0K Jan  8 18:00 .
-rw-r--r--    1  10M Jan 14 12:00 00000000000001028817.index
-rw-r--r--    1  1.2M Jan 14 12:01 00000000000001028817.log
```